# Is there a way to fold all groups of lines that start with a certain word for a .txt file in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been using Visual Studio Code version 1.74.3 on Windows 10 to take all my math notes. So my txt file is mainly composed of the following structure:

[Theorem]

*[Indentation]* Proof:

*[Indentation] [Indentation]* [Proof per see]

Here is an example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vBIn.jpg

I want to fold all the groups of lines that start with the word "Proof" (it occurs 3454 times as of now) because most of the time I don't need to see it, and they're usually quite lengthy.   I want to collapse all the lines immediately below each `Proof` line that share the same indentation.  It's also the case that every proof ends with the character "∎".

The problem is that the file is very long (75k lines) and subdivided into many different regions with different indentation levels, so I cannot just use the "Fold by level K" option, since not all proofs are at the same level.

Therefore, folding all the lines that start with the word "Proof" seems to be the way to go.

I've read the section https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_folding for a way to fold all the lines that start with the word "Proof", but I couldn't find any.

Does anyone know how to do it, or have any other suggestion?

Thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: Is the entire area you want each fold just a single line starting with `Proof` or does the Proof extend below to more lines (if so, delimited by what)?

Comment: Hi! For any given line L that reads "Proof:", I want to collapse all the lines immediately below L that share the same indentation (which is always one level higher than the indentation of L). It's also the case that every proof ends with the character "∎".

Comment: I added a screenshot to show what I mean

Comment: And do you to want to fold them all at once?

Comment: Exactly. I want to be able to fold them all at once, especially because every time I change things around (for instance, cut and paste a whole section containing dozens of proofs), all the folding is undone, and so I need to manually go there and fold each proof again, which takes up useful time

Answer (score 4):

This can be done thanks to the command `editor.createFoldingRangeFromSelection` which will fold anything you can select.  It looks like this `find` would select each of your proof-groups:

```
^[\t ]*Proof[\s\S\n]*?∎         // I didn't thoroughly test this
```

So you could (1) find those using the Find Widget, then

(2) <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (the `editor.action.selectAllMatches` command will select each find match separately) and then

(3) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> to apply the `editor.createFoldingRangeFromSelection` command and it should fold each of those find matches.

To automate this a bit, you can use an extension I wrote, [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform), and this keybinding (in your `keybindings.json`):

```
{
  "key": "alt+c",                 // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "find": "^[\\t ]*Proof[\\s\\S\n]*?∎",   // need double-escaping here
    "isRegex": true,
    "postCommands": [
      "editor.action.selectAllMatches",
      "editor.createFoldingRangeFromSelection"
    ]
  },
  "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && editorLangId == plaintext"
}
```

It does the same find, separately selects each match and then folds it.

[image: fold selected lines]

---

The command `Remove Manual Folding Ranges` will unfold any selected  manually folded range.  So if you wanted to unfold all your proof-ranges at once, this keybinding would work:

```
{
  "key": "alt+d",                    // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "find": "^[\\t ]*Proof[\\s\\S\n]*?∎",
    "isRegex": true,
    "postCommands": [
      "editor.action.selectAllMatches",
      "editor.removeManualFoldingRanges"
    ]
  },
  "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && editorLangId == plaintext"
}
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for your response! The step-wise approach did work! However, a huge problem was created: Now, for some reason, some regions that were foldable before are now not foldable. Here is an example: https://imgur.com/a/8fUUXJM . Line 852 was foldable just like line 351 is (in the sense, all the region below it could collapse, and there was a ∨ arrow just like line 950). But this region (together with countless other ones throughout the file) is not foldable anymore. This actually makes the file almost unusable, and I'm desperately trying to undo this haha

Comment: Can you put that part of the file - lines 350-1500 - somewhere I can access it?  Is there anything different about what is under 852 from what is under 351?

Comment: Sure! I've uploaded the first section of the file (the section on Logic). It contains line 852. Link: https://file.io/PHk97i5Gv9wY . To replicate the problem, remember to use ^[\t ]*Prova[\s\S\n]*?∎ (i.e, replace Proof with the Portuguese word Prova). In this section, other lines that should be foldable include 147, 434, 690, 1073.

Comment: If I go to that `file.io` link it says that `The transfer you have requested has been deleted.`

Comment: No idea what happened! Try this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1APUMNV_1rHrSqgZKFM6NNJsI5bjCaj_w/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I can access that file.  The issue may only be a regex issue, or formatting.  Should line 448 not be folded - the same for all one-liner Provas?  Should fold just 453-462?  In lines 467-563 there are a lot of multi-line Provas, but only one ∎ on line 563.  Is that correct?  Should that whole thing be folded?  Same for lines 694-711?  860-951?  994-1058? 1077-1128, 1141-1248, 1272-1289, 152-178?  Is 183-236 correct as is - the indentation would appear to indicate that it is one Prova.

Comment: I see line 434 is indented the same as the Prova above it but after the `∎`.  Is line 434 part of the above Prova?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251307/discussion-between-mark-and-diego-oliveira).