# VScode how to fold region in a log file

Tags: visual-studio-code, fold

VScode provided some ways to fold regions:

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_folding
- [How do I collapse sections of code in Visual Studio Code for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30067767/how-do-i-collapse-sections-of-code-in-visual-studio-code-for-windows)

For a log file having 330560 lines of text, the `Fold selection` is not a good option, since it is not easy to select thousand of lines. I am able to use things like `#region/#endregion` and convert the log file to C# or python source code file by using `ctrl+shift+p -> Change Language Mode` but I am wondering if any better/less hacking way to fold lines in a text file. e.g using regexp? or add some special marker to let the editor knows a block text is a foldable region?

**Spoiler Alert**: Due to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/90843 makes the VSCode a bad choice for log viewing. It is no good for using VSCode to check logs.

Comment: [This extension](https://github.com/zokugun/vscode-explicit-folding) can do custom folding rules based on regex.

Comment: Can you select your regions by some regex?

Comment: @Mark I am not sure how to use regex to select a region

Comment: There are a number of ways to use a regex to select some code.  Put your regex into a Find Widget and then `Alt+Enter` for example or `Ctrl+Shift+L`.  I was just asking if you are able to craft a regex that would capture what you want to fold.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75190983/is-there-a-way-to-fold-all-groups-of-lines-that-start-with-a-certain-word-for-a/75191133#75191133 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75664233/hide-style-props-in-vscode-extention/75680188#75680188